# Is there a way to profile CPU utilization for ALL java processes on a particular machine?

Tags: performance, jvm, profiling

As described in the title: is there a tool to profile CPU utilization for ALL java processes on a particular machine for a particular time period? seems like most of the existing tool are for single process only.

Comment: Asking for software/tools is EXPLICITLY off-topic

Comment: Some tools allow you to join multiple profile runs into one. But a simple solution is to run all the threads in one JVM to make it easier to profile.

Answer (score 1):

Any profiler can do that, just attach them to all JVMs.